# Any magic to stop linux freezing up?

Tags: ubuntu, memory, crash

I run memory and CPU intensive problems on my linux (Ubuntu 20.04) laptop.

I have seen similar problems online. Can add some links later if needed. As soon as my memory gets above 90-98%, the whole system completely locks up. No control alt delete to save here... Well actually, going to the log out screen sometimes works to unfreeze things so I can kill the python process through system monitor or in my IDE. As my computer gets older it seems to be happening more frequently. Generally I need to do a cold restart.
I have tried the magic key system request REISUB method, and have changed some settings. But my print screen (Dell laptop) does not seem to work.

Can anyone point me in any direction to solve this. Either getting system request to work or to prevent the system freezing up. I have created bash scripts to tell me when memory is running out, but I would prefer a more robust solution.

Thanks.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [earlyoom](https://github.com/rfjakob/earlyoom). I've read many good things about it, but have no personal experience with it and don't feel comfortable writing a full answer for it.

Comment: Ah fantastic I think this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: There is a robust solution: swap space. Read `man mkswap swapon mount fstab`.

Comment: Hmm Interesting solution about the swap space. My breakdown is 15.5GB and 2GB swap. I haven't noticed the swap space being full though, only the memory. I will check this though. So increasing my swap size might help the solution. Also seems a bit dangerous. I will do some research.